# How is java (jdbc) dealing with floating IPs?

Tags: java, postgresql, networking, jdbc

I want to use a floating ip to access a postgresql database (with failover).
I now have a small webservice connecting to the database and running queries against it (`SELECT NOW();`). This seems to work quite well, as long as the IP is changed while no postgres-client is waiting for a response.
I modified the query to `SELECT NOW(), pg_sleep(1)`. Now I run into big trouble, when switching the IP. The service just stops running. It does not throw any Exceptions or reacts to any requests.

You can find the code to create two virtual hosts locally at http://pastie.org/9217890, you'll need to `puppet module install puppetlabs-postgresql` first. `vagrant up` starts two postgres-servers (`192.168.162.101/102`), you can switch the IP `192.168.162.100` with `switch.sh <1/2>`.

Can Java handle switching IPs?
What can I do to have my application not stopping?
Do I try to do something completely stupid?

Comment: The answer is that Java doesn't do anything. It just relies on the same DNS APIs as everyone else does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an open TCP/IP request in flight when the IP switches, PgJDBC never gets a reply, so it stays blocked listening on the socket. It's just as if the remote server lost its Internet connection, crashed, etc.

To deal with this you need client-side keep-alives with short timeouts. Server-side keepalives, as configured in `postgresql.conf` or via `SET` directives, will *not* work for this as they're designed to let the *server* get rid of dead *client* connections.

This principle is the same for PostgreSQL+PgJDBC as for any other service with stateful long-lived TCP connections.

In the case of PgJDBC, to enable keepalives you want the `tcpKeepAlive` directive for your JDBC connection string. I think PgJDBC always uses the Java JVM keepalive defaults, so you may need to set some JVM parameters to tune the keepalive interval and timeout shorter as well.

For most uses, it's instead sufficient to have a PgBouncer instance as a connection proxy. This gets reconfigured to point to the new master on failover. It does mean there's a single point of failure, but it's a nearly stateless and simple one. PgBouncer is much less likely to cause problems than playing games with IP-based failover is.